# Must declare the scalar variable "@OUTSTANDINGSDATA"

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have this code in a SQL SP.

When I'm testing if @OUTSTANDINGSDATA is not null, I get a "Must declare the scalar variable "@OUTSTANDINGSDATA"" error.
It does not happen with the other variables.
Any ideas?
Tks in advance

```
USE [PantaRei]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[InsertDdrsData]    Script Date: 08/22/2012 14:29:28 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertDdrsData] 
@RECEIVABLESDATA RECEIVABLESTABLE READONLY,
@DILUTIONSDATA DILUTIONSTABLE READONLY,
@ACCOUNTABLESDATA ACCOUNTABLESTABLE READONLY,
@OUTSTANDINGSDATA OUTSTANDINGSTABLE READONLY,
@TABLE1 VARCHAR(MAX),
@TABLE2 VARCHAR(MAX),
@TABLE3 VARCHAR(MAX),
@TABLE4 VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    DECLARE @CMD nvarchar(345)

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SET @TABLE1 = RTRIM(@TABLE1)
    SET @TABLE2 = RTRIM(@TABLE2)
    SET @TABLE3 = RTRIM(@TABLE3)

    SELECT * INTO #t1 FROM @RECEIVABLESDATA

    SET @CMD =

        'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@TABLE1) +
        'SELECT * FROM #t1'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @CMD

    SELECT * INTO #t2 FROM @DILUTIONSDATA

    SET @CMD =

        'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@TABLE2) +
        'SELECT * FROM #t2'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @CMD

    SELECT * INTO #t3 FROM @ACCOUNTABLESDATA

    SET @CMD =

        'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@TABLE3) +
        'SELECT * FROM #t3'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @CMD

    IF @OUTSTANDINGSDATA IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            SELECT * INTO #t4 FROM @OUTSTANDINGSDATA

            SET @CMD =

                'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@TABLE4) +
                'SELECT * FROM #t4'

            EXECUTE sp_executesql @CMD

        END 
END
```

Comment: you sure OUTSTANDINGSTABLE exists?  no fat fingered spelling mistakes?

Comment: also, passing in 4 different tables?! probably means you should rethink your DB design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@OUTSTANDINGSDATA` is a Table Valued Parameter.

It can't be `NULL` even if not passed in. Test for an empty table instead.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @OUTSTANDINGSDATA)
```

Comment: it works. I just empty the table instead of passing a null. Tks

Answer (score 0):

It's not valid to pass `NULL` as the value of a table valued parameter.

Maybe you need to check whether it's empty instead?

---

E.g.:

```
CREATE TYPE LocationTableType AS TABLE 
( LocationName VARCHAR(50)
, CostRate INT );
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_InsertProductionLocation
    @TVP LocationTableType READONLY
    AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT *
        FROM  @TVP;
GO
EXEC dbo.usp_InsertProductionLocation NULL
```

Produces the error:

```
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure usp_InsertProductionLocation, Line 0
Operand type clash: NULL is incompatible with LocationTableType
```

---

Oops - per Martin's comment, you don't have to *supply* a value as a parameter - but it still will not be `NULL` inside the stored procedure. An empty instance of the table will be automatically supplied.

Comment: The parameter doesn't have to be supplied. Just call `EXEC dbo.usp_InsertProductionLocation`. Still won't be `NULL` though.